# Getting null in response with get API

Tags: flutter

Hello I have this package [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http#-readme-tab-)

Have it, in the file `pubspec.yaml` on dependencies `http: ^0.12.0+2`
. I get the packages.

Import

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Code

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$API_KEY'
);
```

I debug it and the value of response is always null. So I never know the status code of the response. I also try it with other APIs but I have the same problem. I search the URL on the website and it gives me a JSON, that is what I'm looking for.

Any suggestion?
[Debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8N8I.png)

I also try an example and it fails.

```flutter
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={http}";

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted responce.
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
    print("Number of books about http: $itemCount.");
  } else {
    print("Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.");
  }
}
```

Comment: put it in try catch and print the exception

Comment: @ArashMohammadi but that's not the problem, the problem is that always returns null

Comment: I am not receiving null, it has response.body, the response code is 401 because of api key, but it is not null on my end, you need to try catch it to know what is the problem

Comment: @ArashMohammadi can I see your code?

Comment: Have you managed the $ signs? I'll put my code in the answers, hope that will help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for my problem was the Android manifest, I'm new and I didn't know what that it can't have newlines in blank, so I join it and it works. I'm crying XD

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for me:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class StackOverflow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackOverflowState createState() => _StackOverflowState();
}

class _StackOverflowState extends State<StackOverflow> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getHttp().then((response){
      print('response code = '+ response.statusCode.toString());
    });

  }

  Future<http.Response> _getHttp() async {
    String latitude = 'latitude';
    String longitude = 'longitude';
    String aPI_KEY = 'API_KEY';

    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$aPI_KEY');
        return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception = ' + e.toString());
      throw Exception(e);
    }


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Comment: well just put them in try catch and print the exception, ill edit the answer with try catch

Comment: Not working :( it's something that's not the code or I don't know :(

Comment: so the `print('Exception = ' + e.toString());` did not get called? Then we need the whole code to debug this.

Comment: Go forward one more line, in debug. Then see whats in the response or it jumps to catch

Comment: so when the response is null I don't know why but it does like an exit of the function

Answer (score 0):

update your manifest
add this uses library inside Application {Image 1}

```
   <uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
```

and also make a network security config xml file and add this inside res folder {Image 2}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
<!--    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">-->
<!--&lt;!&ndash;        <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--    </domain-config>-->
</network-security-config>
```

and update your manifest by adding metadata {Image 3}

```
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
    android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
```

[image: Add library]

[image: Add xml file]

[image: Update manifest like this]